# Why default arguments in F# (FSharpOption<T>) are reference types?

Tags: f#, optional-arguments

C# and F# has different implementation of the default (or optional) parameters.

In C# language when you add default value to the argument you'll not change its underlying type (I mean type of the parameter). Actually optional arguments in C# is a lightweight syntactic sugar:

```
class CSharpOptionalArgs
{
  public static void Foo(int n = 0) {}
}

// Somewhere in the call site

CSharpOptionalArgs.Foo();
// Call to Foo() will be transformed by C# compiler
// *at compile time* to something like:
const int nArg = GetFoosDefaultArgFromTheMetadata();
CSharpOptionalArgs.Foo(nArg);
```

But F# implements this feature in a different way. Unlike C#, F# optional arguments resolves at *callee* site but not at *caller* site:

```
type FSharpOptionalArgs() =
    static let defaultValue() = 42

    static member public Foo(?xArg) =
        // Callee site decides what value to use if caller does not specifies it
        let x = defaultArg xArg (defaultValue())
        printfn "x is %d" x
```

This implementation is absolutely reasonable and much more powerful. C# optional arguments restricted only to compile-time constants (because optional arguments stored in assemblies metadata). In F# default value could be less obvious but we can use arbitrary expression as a default value. So far so good.

F# optional arguments transformed by F# compiler to `Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption<'a>` which is a **reference type**. This means that every **call to the method with optional argument in F# will lead to additional allocation at the managed head and will lead to pressure to garbage collection**.

```
**EDITED**
// This call will NOT lead to additional heap allocation!
FSharpOptionalArgs.Foo()
// But this one will do!
FSharpOptionalArgs.Foo(12)
```

I don't worry about application code, but this behavior could dramatically degrade performance for libraries. What if some library method with an optional argument will be called thousands times per second?

**This implementation seems really odd to me. But maybe there is some rules that library developer should avoid using of this feature or F# team is going to change this behavior in the future version of F#?**

Following unit test profs that optional arguments are reference type:

```
[<TestFixture>]
type FSharpOptionalArgumentTests() =

    static member public Foo(?xArg) =
        // Callee site decides what value to use if caller does not specifies it
        let x = defaultArg xArg 42
        ()

    [<Test>]
    member public this.``Optional argument is a reference type``() =
        let pi = this.GetType().GetMethod("Foo").GetParameters() |> Seq.last

        // Actually every optional parameter in F# is a reference type!!
        pi.ParameterType |> should not' (equal typeof<int>)
        pi.ParameterType.IsValueType |> should be False
        ()
```

Comment: For the sake of completeness: Option is annotated with http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370528.aspx, so if argument is omitted - None=null will be passed instead.

Comment: So this means that for "default" values we'll not allocate any objects in managed heap, but for "non-default" values we'll do?

Answer (score 5):

Because nobody in F# team is not interesting yet in compiling "simple", `Option`-like discriminated unions as value types, supporting pattern-matching over such unions and so on :)

Remember, tuples types are heavly used in functional languages like F# (much more than default arguments), but still implemented in CLR as refererence types - nobody cares about memory allocation and functional_languages-specific GC tweaks.

Comment: I should clarify that F# is able expand typle types into multiple parameters where possible, but return values of tuple types and tuple usage in high-order functions (like `Seq.map (fun (x, y) -> x + y)`) always produces heap allocations and GC pressure.

Comment: Its clear that no one in the near future will tune CLR only to one particular language, especially for F#. But its possible to "tune" language in this case relatively easyly. For example, Nemerle uses simple optimization for tuples and complile "small" tuples (with less than 4 args, I think) as structs and "large" tuples as classes. It seems possible to use similar optimization for tuples and optional arguments as well.

Comment: Don't forget about struct tuples!

Answer (score 1):

F# 4.1 has C# optional attribute compatibility. However if you are developing function that will be consumed also by F# then you should use regular syntax:

`member this.M (?i : int) = 
    let iv = defaultArg i 12
        iv + 1`

F# 4.1 optional arguments documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/members/methods